# PHP Correct way to call mysqli using Intelephense

Tags: php, mysqli

This code triggers my editor's intelephense for error:

```
/**
 * Connect to database
 */
public function link() {
    global $config; mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);
    try {
        return new \mysqli($config['db_hostname'], $config['db_username'], $config['db_password'], $config['db_name']);
    } catch (\exception $e) {
        throw new \exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
    }
}
```

> Expected 6 arguments. Found 4.intelephense(10005)

would it be fine if I just use:

```
return new \mysqli($config['db_hostname'], $config['db_username'], $config['db_password'], $config['db_name'],null,null);
```

Thank you all for answering; also deceze who corrected me on wrong way to catch exception;

this is edited code:

```
/**
 * Connect to database
 */
public function link() {
    global $config; mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    try {
        return new \mysqli($config['db_hostname'], $config['db_username'], $config['db_password'], $config['db_name'], ini_get('mysqli.default_port'), ini_get('mysqli.default_socket'));
    } catch (\exception $e) {
        echo 'Cannot connect to a database server'; die();
    }
}
```

note ,this is for withing the class using namespaces...

Comment: what editor and intellisense is that? Because 4 arguments are totally valid, and I personally would not want to set the port to `null`

Comment: They are optional args for a reason, if your ide / intellisense is telling you that's not okay, it's wrong.

Comment: Sounds like a broken editor that isn't being realistic.

Comment: are u using `127.0.0.1` as a hostname?

Comment: bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client for vs code, I quite like it but I guess it has quirks with optional parameters

Comment: Why catch the exception to immediately rethrow it as a new exception…?

Comment: I had the same issue when I used that intelephense. Try using PHP IntelliSense by Felix Becker `felixfbecker.php-intellisense`

Comment: @Second2None  I already tried that, its buggy, slow and not nearly as good; for the Intelephense, there has already being patch released, and should solve this issues;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intelephense plugin uses the stubs from PhpStorm. The author already submitted a PR to fix this (and other functions with optional parameters): https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs/pull/520.

As soon as that's merged and the stubs are updated, you should no longer receive the problem reported in vscode.

There should be no need to change your constructor call, it is valid code and will execute without problems.